# Android ListView - freeze vertical position on horizontal move event

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I've got this strange issue.
I have a volume control application.
In my ListView, I have some custom elements, that I can use to change the volume of a specific application. In this custom element, I have a listener for MotionEvents, what mostly monitor the motionEvent.getX() coordinate to calculate volume changes.

For example, this is my view right now: [AppListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4yLI.png)
Simply you can touch an element and move your finger horizontally, the colored line and the numbers will change on the fly.

My problem is when I try to change volume and I make some vertical movement too, the events on the application will be canceled because scroll event occurred.

I've tried to disable the scroll of ListView in so many ways, but the most of it just simply disabled all of the touch events too.

How can I detect horizontal movement and disable the scroll until the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP action?

Or

Can you suggest me another solution without ListView?

(The ListView is in a SwipeDownRefreshLayout.)

Thanks!

Comment: You can add transparent view inside recycle view and when user   slide that specific position you can try to change volume.

Comment: did you try returning **true** from **onTouch** or whichever event from which you are processing the horizontal movement so that the system understands the event is handled.

Comment: on my element the returning value of onTouchEvent is true, but on vertical movement the listview scroll catches the event and a MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL stops my onTouchEvent handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.
In my custom adapter, I have an `onTouchListener`, in the `onTouch` I just added this line:

 `view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`

`true` when `ACTION_DOWN` and `false` when `ACTION_UP`